# Description of what kinds of questions are appropriate

Tags: discussion, policy

On the old MO site, we had an extensive FAQ describing the purpose of MO and the kinds of questions that are welcome.  Right now, I don't see any way for a new user to figure out what we're about and how we differ from [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).  I see this leading to lots of unnecessarily hurt feelings.  How shall we deal with it?

Comment: When a new user visits an SE2.0 site there is text on top that suggests the user visit the [about] page. The top section of the about page is editable by moderators. That is a good place I think to explain the scope of MO and how it differs from [math.se].

Comment: Absolutely; this is rather urgent. What do we do now when somebody posts an off-topic question?

Comment: Angelo: I found the old "how-to-ask" here: http://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you check out the meta.MSE site you can find all sort of FAQ posts with explanations and whatnot. It's reasonable that meta.MO will have such posts as well.

Answer (score 4):

There's an extensive help system built into the site, with a directory of pages here: https://mathoverflow.net/help

By default, moderators here can edit this page: https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic and certain sections of this one: https://mathoverflow.net/about (including the example question shown, although at the moment it hasn't quite figured out that there are questions here yet).

If additional pages or customizations are needed, don't hesitate to ask - it's not always possible, but we'll see what we can do.